# ogr_fdw compile error `Fatal error: can't create ogr_fdw.o: Permission denied`

Tags: make, postgresql, makefile

I'm trying to install PostGIS on Ubuntu 17.04 and I've been following this [guide](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS23UbuntuPGSQL96Apt#ogr_fdwforeigndatawrapperforspatialdata) to the point. Everything works perfectly, but when work my way down to install [ogr_fdw foreign data wrapper for spatial data](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS23UbuntuPGSQL96Apt#ogr_fdwforeigndatawrapperforspatialdata) and run `make && make install` I run into this assembler error.

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create ogr_fdw.o: Permission denied
<builtin>: recipe for target 'ogr_fdw.o' failed
make: *** [ogr_fdw.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need sudo for the install  `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you linked unnecessarily prepend the `git clone` command with `sudo`

```
sudo git clone -b master https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw.git pgsql_ogr_fdw
```

This causes the whole cloned directory tree to be owned by `root`, preventing the compiler from writing files there when run as a normal user.

I suggest you start over, removing the cloned directory

```
sudo rm -rf pgsql_ogr_fdw
```

and then start over **without** `sudo`

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw.git pgsql_ogr_fdw
```

Comment: I still get the failure after that step is taken...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Honestly, just use `sudo -s` to swith to root and then it would work perfectly (did for me).